# unauthorized_client when validating Play Games server code on cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-play-games

I'm using the following cloud function to verify a play games `serverAuthToken` sent from my game:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const verifier = require("gamecenter-identity-verifier");
const {defineSecret} = require("firebase-functions/params");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const cors = require("cors")({origin: true});
const {google} = require("googleapis");

const serverClientId = defineSecret("SERVER_CLIENT_ID");
const serverClientSecret = defineSecret("SERVER_CLIENT_SECRET");

admin.initializeApp();
const auth = admin.auth();

const BUNDLE_ID = "com.bundle.id"; // in my app this is the real one

exports.pgAuth = functions
    .runWith({secrets: [serverClientId, serverClientSecret ]})
    .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      return cors(req, res, async () => {
        const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
            serverClientId.value(),
            serverClientSecret.value(),
            "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        );
        await oauth2Client.getToken(req.body.code);
        const result = await auth.createCustomToken(req.body.playerId);
        res.json({result});
      });
    });
```

The token I'm using is the one registered as the server token on my published game:

[image]

And it lists the correct id token:

[image]

Which has the correct callback URI from the JS code:

[image]

But I'm getting the following error when I run the cloud function:

```js
Error: unauthorized_client at Gaxios._request (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:130:23) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) at async OAuth2Client.getTokenAsync (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:125:21) at async /workspace/index.js:30:9
```

As it's my first time implementing this flow I'm not exactly sure what I'm going wrong. I've verified that the id and secret are in fact those for my token, so my assumption is that the client represented by `serverClientId` and `serverClientSecret` lacks certain authorizations or that I'm using the wrong Google library. But I'm not sure. Any tips would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question - I supplied an incorrect client id on android when creating the server code. Changing to the correct client id fixed it!